# Number of ways a handshaking can take place

Tags: combinatorics

There is a group of 9 people. Each person shakes hands with exactly two others. I need to consider 2 handshaking arrangements different if and only if at least two people who shake hands under one arrangement do not shake hands under the other arrangement. I need to find the number of such arrangements possible. The condition  which is given is troubling. Can anyone help me with a simple combinatorial solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph will be a union of cycles. 
The sizes of these cycles add up to $9$. 
As every cycle has size at least $3$, there are only four possibilities:

One cycle of lenght $9$.

Two cycles of lengths $3,6$.

Two cycles of lengths $4,5$.

Three cycles of lengths $3,3,3$.

Each of these four cases lead to a simple combinatorial problem. I show you the first and the last cases, you can finish the rest.

Preliminary calculation: Given $k\geq 3$ people, there are $(k-1)!/2$ ways to form a $k$-cycle out of them. Indeed, there are $(k-1)!$ cyclic orders of them, and each cyclic order defines the same cycle graph as the reverse cyclic order, and there are no other coincidences.

First case: the graph is a $9$-cycle. There are $(9-1)!/2=20160$ ways to make them form a $9$-cycle.

Last case: the graph is a union of three $3$-cycles. There are $\frac{9!}{(3!)^3\cdot 3!}=280$ ways to partition the $9$ people into three groups of $3$, and this uniquely determines a solution, as three people form a uique $3$-cycle.

Have fun with the rest of the proof, no new idea is needed.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance what does "circles" mean in your solution?

Comment: Did I write that anywhere? If I did, it is equivalent to cycle.

Comment: Is something still unclear? Do you find the answer acceptable?

Comment: yeah I actually didn't understand how you made those cycle lengths,etc

Comment: Be more specific, please.

Comment: What exactly does a cycle mean?

Comment: Cycle graph: $C_n$ with vertices $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ such that the edges are exactly $v_1v_2, v_2v_3, v_3v_4, \ldots, v_{n-1}v_n, v_nv_1$. But seriously, though, please use google for such trivialities: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CycleGraph.html
It is literally the first result if you google "cycle graph".